# Dataframe-Compare list of columns' values against one column's value with multiple criteria - vectorized

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the below dataframe:

```
Com1       a       b       c        d       e      f       g      
0.83389 0.83585 0.8351  0.83493 0.83683 0.83697 0.83622 0.83573    
0.83375 0.83585 0.8351  0.83493 0.83683 0.83487 0.83357 0.83147    
0.83366 0.83585 0.8351  0.83493 0.83683 0.83567 0.83487 0.83357    
0.834   0.83585 0.8351  0.83493 0.83567 0.83147 0.82807 0.82257
```

What I need is to compare the letter columns to the Com1 column.  In plain language, the formula is:

```
ColList = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
if any number in ColList is > Com1 and < (Com1 +0.001):
    Result = 0
else:
    Result = 1
```

The desired result is:

```
Com1       a       b       c        d       e      f       g         Result
0.83389 0.83585 0.8351  [0.83473]   0.83683 0.83697 0.83622 0.83573    0
0.83375 0.83585 0.8351  0.83493 0.83683 0.83487 0.83357 0.83147        1
0.83366 0.83585 0.8351  0.83493 0.83683 0.83567 0.83487 0.83357        1
0.834   0.83585 0.8351  [0.83493]   0.83567 0.83147 0.82807 0.82257    0
```

(I bracketed the numbers that are causing the "0" result)

I tried to use np.where, but it did not yield the correct results when I manually compared in excel.  The formula I tried was:

```
ColList = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
df['Result'] = np.where( (df[ColList ].gt(df['Com1'],axis=0).any(axis=1)) & (df[ColList ].lt(df['Com1'] + 0.001,axis=0).any(axis=1)),0,1)
```

I also considered using the between() function, but from my research, since its a list of columns, I am not having a series and it cannot be used.

I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply with `axis=1` to work on the rows with the help of a function:

```
def between(s: pd.Series):
    ColList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    return int(not any(s[ColList].between(s['Com1'], s['Com1']+0.001)))


df['result'] = df.apply(between, axis=1)
```

If you want you could also have the column list and column to compare to as argument and use partial before applying it.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you for teaching about apply as another way.  If anyone is reading this in the future, the equivalent to Less Than and Greater Than, need to include in the between method ```inclusive='neither'```

Answer (score 0):

For vectorized operations, you could use `gt` and `lt` methods to get boolean frames and combine them using `&` operator and combine across rows using `any`:

```
cols = df.drop(columns='Com1')
out = (1-(cols.gt(df['Com1'], axis=0) & 
       cols.lt(df['Com1']+0.001, axis=0))
       .any(axis=1).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Note that the output I get here is different from the one you get because the input given is different from the input used to derive the desired output.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you.  If you have some time to, is it possible to explain the formula in a breakdown?  Then, I can learn the principles behind it.

Comment: @JonathanStearns With `gt`, we create a df where each cell is True if its value is greater than the value of `Com1` in the corresponding row, False otherwise. Similarly, with `lt`, we create a df where each cell is True if its value is less than the value of `Com1+0.001` in the corresponding row. By combining the two using `&`, we create `com1<val<com1+0.001` for each cell. Then `any` looks for at least one True in each row.